# Python 3.x - Pandas conditional logic field value assignment - another field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a conditional assignment in a Pandas dataframe with three date columns, from which a baseline date will be derived using a fourth categorical value ('table').

The code below runs BUT I get the text `pd_date` or `nd_date` (i.e., the text of the field name), not the date value from the field. Both date fields are `datetime` fields, and `BaseDate` not previously defined.

```
df.loc[df['table'].isin(['t1','t2']), ['BaseDate'] = df['pd_date']]

df.loc[df['table'].isin(['t3','t4']), ['BaseDate'] = df['nd_date']]
```

I have seen many, many questions on assigning values based on fields here on SE, but cannot find anything related to assigning field values. I tried the less desirable method of defining a function and using `.apply`, but that was messier and had the same problem - returned a string, not a field value.

I know this must be something simple, but I cannot work it out. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create some test data and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accepts scalar labels and can be used for setting data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['t1', 123, 456], ['t3', 789, 876]],
                  columns=['table', 'pd_date', 'nd_date'])

df.loc[df['table'].isin(['t1','t2']), 'BaseDate'] = df['pd_date']
df.loc[df['table'].isin(['t3','t4']), 'BaseDate'] = df['nd_date']

print(df)

  table  pd_date  nd_date  BaseDate
0    t1      123      456     123.0
1    t3      789      876     876.0
```

You may find it cleaner to use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['BaseDate'] = np.where(df['table'].isin(['t1','t2']), df['pd_date'], df['nd_date'])
```

Comment: Thank you! np.where worked! I am not a fan of nested where - I thought .loc would be the more elegant and Pythonic solution, but at this point, it works. Thank you for this.

Comment: Done - thanks again. Any posters who have a .loc based solution, I would love to see that as well.

Comment: @SteveR, My first solution includes `loc` as well (a bit further up) :)

Comment: Yes, your original solution did use .loc, which I appreciate - but unfortunately, I was unable to get the code, which is identical to what I had actually originally posted, pasted from my project, to work properly - I kept getting the text 'nd_date' instead of the actual date. I do appreciate the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you are trying to do is rename the column. I would try it like this.

```
tableOne = df.loc[df['table'].isin(['t1','t2'])]

tableOne.rename(index=str, columns={"pd_date": "BaseDate")

tableTwo = df.loc[df['table'].isin(['t1','t2'])]

tableTwo.rename(index=str, columns={"nd_date": "BaseDate")

df = pd.concat([tableOne,tableTwo])
```

Comment: No, I am trying to assign the value of one of three date columns to a new, fourth date column based on the categorical value in a string column.